# Why am I getting "classes must have either one (and only one) constructor" error?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have been trying to get Guice working but end up with this:

> Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor

My interface:

```
public interface AddrBookStore {
    public Contact getContactByKey(String key);
    public void addContact(Contact c);
}
```

The implementation:

```
public class RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore implements AddrBookStore {
    private Connection connection;

    public RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public Contact getContactByKey(String key) throws AddrBookException
    {} 
    @Override
    public void addContact(Contact c) throws AddrBookException
    {}
}
```

The binding module:

```
public class ABguiceConfingModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {        
        bind(AddrBookStore.class).to(RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore.class);
    }
}
```

The `AddrBook` client where I am injecting:

```
public class AddrBook {
    private AddrBookStore store;

    @Inject
    public AddrBook(AddrBookStore store)
    {
        this.store = store;
    }
    ... other methods;
}
```

And my main:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ABguiceConfingModule() );
        AddrBookStore store = injector.getInstance( AddrBookStore.class );

        AddrBook book = new AddrBook(store);
        AddrBookCLI cli = new AddrBookCLI(book);
        cli.interact(new InputStreamReader(System.in), new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

}}
```

After all this, I'm getting this error:

```
1) Could not find a suitable constructor in addrbook.store.RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
[ERROR] at addrbook.store.RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore.class(RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore.java:23)
[ERROR] at addrbook.ABguiceConfingModule.configure(ABguiceConfingModule.java:13)
```

I have experience with Spring and not with Guice. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The error message says you must have either a constructor annotated with @Inject, or it must have a non-private zero-argument constructor. The code you show for the  ABguiceConfingModule  class does not have any such constructor.

Comment: I imagine Fred means RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore has no such constructor, which I agree with. Modules like ABguiceConfingModule can have any constructor you want, because you're calling it yourself to feed into createInjector. You'll probably want to add an @Inject annotation to RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore and make sure Connection is bound in one of your modules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You haven't set up the primary dependency for `AddrBookStore`. You need to have a binding for `Connection`, and then you need to annotate the constructor with `@Inject`.

You've set up the `AddrBookStore` class but clearly it's wrapping an Rdbms... except you haven't set up the `Rdbms`.

There are lots of ways to do this in Guice, in this case I would probably do it with a `Provider<Connection>`, that way you have an entire class to put the code for spinning up your connection to the database, so something like:

```
public class ConnectionProvider implements Provider<Connection> {
    public Connection get() {
        // put your code that connects to the database here
    }
}
```

Then your module would be:

```
public class ABguiceConfingModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(AddrBookStore.class).to(RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore.class);
        bind(Connection.class).toProvider(ConnectionProvider.class);
    }
}
```

And then finally your `AddrBookStore`:

```
public class RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore implements AddrBookStore {
    private Connection connection;

    @Inject
    public RdbmsBasedAddrBookStore(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public Contact getContactByKey(String key) throws AddrBookException
    {}

    @Override
    public void addContact(Contact c) throws AddrBookException
    {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solution worked. The only problem i find is if tommorow, i may want to change the impltementation to say file base storage or into some nosql db, like `bind(AddrBookStore.class).to(FileBasedAddrBookStore.class);` I will have to create another  binding similar to what you have mentioned in the configmodule `bind(File.class).toProvider(FileProvider.class);`

Comment: @KartzKartel that's correct, in Guice if you want to change the binding you have to make a code change (to the module), it's not just a config XML file like Spring. However you could argue Guice is more powerful because you get the full language to spin up your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error message because I forget to add annotation `@Inject`  on constructor.     `public AddrBook(AddrBookStore store)` in the case of this question.